# Lost parameter value during SQL trace in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have implemented an approach for tracing SQL queries from EF Core according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging. And have problems with tracing query parameters. When I receive Log events in all values of DbParameterLogData I see only the question mark instead of the actual values which I passed to the query.

[image]

I am using VS 2015.

Comment: That looks very much like the value *is* the string `"?"`. How did you build the query?

Comment: No. For example query from other context but with the same result: `IQueryable<Agreement> query = _agreements.Where(a => a.AgreementNumber == filter.AgreementNumber);` And I'm shure, that filter.AgreementNumber have value differ from '?'

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is the default behavior of EF Core (filling up the [`DbParameterLogData.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.dbparameterlogdata#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Storage_DbParameterLogData_Value) property with `"?"`).

In order to get the real parameter values, you need to enable *sensitive data logging* by using [`DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder_EnableSensitiveDataLogging) method:

> Enables application data to be included in exception messages, logging, etc. This can include the values assigned to properties of your entity instances, **parameter values for commands being sent to the database**, and other such data. You should only enable this flag if you have the appropriate security measures in place based on the sensitivity of this data.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes this results in a `MissingMethodException`. In which case, you should call it in `ConfigureServices()`: `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging())`

Comment: A little debugging trick.      
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
        }