# Entity Framework Core tries to reinsert navigation property on save after AddRange

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have the following model:

```
[Table("Facts")]
public partial class Facts
{
  [Key]
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public Guid UserID { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey(nameof(UserID))]
  public Users Users { get; set; }
  //other properties are ommitted
}
```

Its migration code:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Facts",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                UserID = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            //other properties are ommitted
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Facts", x => x.ID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Facts_Users_UserID",
                    column: x => x.UserID,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "ID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

As it has a navigation property, I set it to an existing ID (it is required).

This is the saving method:

```
 public async Task SaveData<T>(List<T> data, bool isNew) where T : class
 {
   if (data == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
   try
   {
     if (isNew)
       context.Set<T>().AddRange(data);
     else
     {
       context.Set<T>().AttachRange(data);
       data.ForEach(d => (context as DbContext).Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified);
     }
     await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {       
     throw;
   }
 }
```

When I enter the save method, I have the following state (the ID is set, the navigation property object is null):

[image]

After `AddRange`, I have the following state (the ID is set, the navigation property object is *not null*):

[image]

Inside the catch, I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint failed'

It looks like it tries to add the navigation property object as a new item to the database.

How can I prevent the reinsert of the already existing navigation property?

**UPDATE**

After enabling the SQL logging, I get the following information (@p0 is the PK, @p18 is the FK):

```
Failed executing DbCommand (105ms) [Parameters=[@p0='84ddca86-3f8a-41f1-aaed-2c65bd1cb384' (DbType = String),...@p18='e33f7939-bc35-4d82-b68b-e1cc0cf32ff1' (DbType = String)...]
INSERT INTO "Facts" ("ID", ... "UserID",...)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29);
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
```

**UPDATE2**

I made some emulator testing and I found out the following.

The data of `Users` table is inserted initially via a SQL script, with the following code:

```
public async virtual Task ExecuteCommandAsync(string sqlCommand)
{
  await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(new RawSqlString(sqlCommand));
}
```

As you can see, the record exists:

[image]

When I save an unrelated data with `SaveData`, its ID is stored as *binary data*:

[image]

So maybe Entity Framework Core is somehow confused when trying to convert binary data to text? Still don't know why retrieve works normally then.

Comment: It's probably the opposite - `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` means it tries to insert record with non existing FK.

Comment: @IvanStoev It makes sense, but the record does exist, I can query it and it is returned. What could cause this kind of FK misconfiguration?

Comment: I don't know. Try turning [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on with [sensitive data logging enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202478/lost-parameter-value-during-sql-trace-in-ef-core/44207235#44207235) to see SQL commands and the parameters.

Comment: I did that and updated the question with the log.

Comment: So record with `e33f7939-bc35-4d82-b68b-e1cc0cf32ff1` exists in `Users` table? Could this possibly be a conversion issue - what is type of the db column (apparently SQLite does not support Guid natively)? Probably some sort of text, then does the exact casing match? Also are we sure that's the failing FK constraint (the error message of course does not telling us), i.e. do you have other FKs in `Facts` table?

Comment: I updated the initial question. There is no other FK inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with ef core when using it in a non awaited asyncron task or in other concurrent scenarios. Try awaiting save changes.

EDIT: It does have another case when is behaving like this, the case when you are using data from 2 different dbContext instances.