# How to debug EF Core 2 CurrentValues.SetValues

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to debug how ef core 2 is updating an entity via `CurrentValues.SetValues` the call to a repo Update is working for most entities but not for this one and I can't tell what the value it is trying to convert because the property used for the updat is a datetime. The value used to update is a datetime as well,  `var today = DateTime.UtcNow;`

#### repo call

```
   public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T t, object key)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return null;
        T exist = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(key);
        if (exist != null)
        {
            _context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return exist;
    }
```

#### code calling update

```
   foreach (var detail in details)
   {
       detail.IsActive = isActive;
       detail.ModifiedDate = today;
       detail.ModifiedBy = currentUserId;

      await _repository.UpdateAsync(detail, detailId);

                //updates.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                //{
                //    await _repository.UpdateAsync(detail, detailId);
                //}));
     }

     //prior attempt is using WaitAll but for debugging, the call
     // is made in the foreach loop
     // if (updates.Count > 0)
     //           Task.WaitAll(updates.ToArray());
```

This is as much output that I can find that EF generates, the update sql:

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [PaymentSyncDetails] SET [IsActive] = @p0, [ModifiedBy] = @p1,  [ModifiedDate] = @p2
  WHERE [PaymentSyncDetailID] = @p3;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

I need to inspect the parameters, @p2 in particular

Comment: set a breakpoint after your call to `SetValues(t)` and inspect the original and current values for the properties you're interested in

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you should use the SQL Server Profiler available in the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: By the way, returning `null` when you're attempting to update a non-existent entity sounds like a horrible code smell. That's an exception, not a "silently ignore" situation

Comment: If you just want to see SQL command parameters, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202478/lost-parameter-value-during-sql-trace-in-ef-core/44207235#44207235. Other than that, you can't (and there is no need) to debug `SetValues` - all it does it to set all primitive properties (except the PK) of the target with the corresponding property values from the source.